# Yii2 Try Catch redirect

Tags: php, yii2

I try to manage integrity constraints in a way that stays user friendly.
User tries to delete something - on error I want to stay on the page and just set an error message

I tried this kind of code :

```
try {
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app','flash.delete.success'));
}catch(\Exception $e) {
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', Yii::t('app', 'error.delete'));
}
$this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('index'));
```

But in case of error it redirects WITHOUT showing the message and if I go then to another page it shows the message (too late)

Can't see why he's doing this !
Some help would be nice :)

Comment: the setFlash is managed  by a proper widget and is executed  .. normally in the layout so is visible in the rendered  page ... setFlash is not like an alert() for javascript ..

Comment: Try to replace `Yii::app()->user->setFlash` to `Yii::app()->session->setFlash`. How do you send delete request (AJAX or regular http request)? May be target page (that will open after redirect) doen't contain widget for flash rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems:

- for redirect must use return: `return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);`
- for transaction on exception before seting flash do rollback: `$transaction->rollBack();`
- sometime on exception before setting flash close db: `Yii::$app->db->close();`